# Pseudo Random generator based on real random seed

Tags: randomness, vrf

I have a big array of numbers and need to choose X of them randomly without repetition.
I have a real random seed provided by an external oracle.

Is there a known fair algorithm to create a pseudo random generator based on the seed?

I read another answer that proposes the usage of modulo operator:
Does something like this give an equal chance to each index?

(consider it untested pseudo-code)

```
uint256[10000] big_list_of_numbers;
seed = very_big_77_digits_number;
uint256[] results;

for(uint256 i =0; i< numbers_to_retrieve; i++) {
  uint256 random_index = seed % big_list_of_numbers.length;
  results.push(big_list_of_numbers[random_index])
  seed = seed - random_index
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [StackOS's lottery implementation](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x80a44A37B9198F5fa5C2F4EF2748cF109A288174#code) - they have a function `getRandomNumber` that uses Link to generate a random seed `randomNumber`; it then uses hash on the seed+nonce to generate a random number.

They have an interesting way to avoid duplicates, the randomized number must be <= participants length, and each time a participant wins, it's moved to the end of the array so it won't be chosen again.

Applying this method on your code (untested) -

```
uint256[10000] big_list_of_numbers;
seed = very_big_77_digits_number;
uint256[] results;

for(uint256 i = 0; i < numbers_to_retrieve; i++) {
  uint256 random_index = uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(seed + i))) % (big_list_of_numbers.length - i);
  results.push(big_list_of_numbers[random_index]);

  big_list_of_numbers[random_index] =  big_list_of_numbers[big_list_of_numbers.length - i - 1];
  big_list_of_numbers[big_list_of_numbers.length - i - 1] = results[i];
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this helped me a lot !